# Crontab not able to start maven services

Tags: spring, bash, spring-boot, cron

Hi everybody I got a problem I programmed a shell to start some spring-boot services automatically when I run this bash script manually everything runs fine but if I run it automatically from the server crontab it is not working the services are not starting can you help me please?
please find down below the code of my bash script:

```
echo "Service1"
cd /home/Location1/subfolder/search/
nohup mvn spring-boot:run &
```

Best Regards
Ro

Comment: Did you check your permission to file? `chmod +x`

Comment: the bash have the appropriate permissions

Comment: Please provide the crontab entry.

Comment: Don't... Please don't use maven to start your program. Instead, properly create a jar and execute that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to give full path to mvn

```
which mvn
```

Then use full path to your crontab

```
nohup /full/path/to/mvn spring-boot:run &
```

Comment: thanks, I just tried it and still not working from crontab